# Sequential functions if one is true

Tags: javascript, forms, function, validation, new-window

I'm trying to create a simple form validator in javascript where when the validation function is true, it moves onto the next function which is open a new window with the text they entered is displayed. However, I'm not 100% sure on the right syntax, I've come across a lot of different variations yet none of them seem to work, and I'm wondering if I'm doing something fundamentally wrong.

This is the javascript contained in my HTML;

```js
<form name="webPage"">
          Please type anything over 5 characters: <input type="text" name="txt2" ><br/>
  
          <input type="submit" name="b2" value="Confirm" onClick="if(validate2()); openWin();">
          </form>
```

and here is my js file with my functions saved in it;

```js
function validate2() {
 var valTxt = document.webPage.txt2.value;
 if (valTxt==null || valTxt==""){
  alert("Field cannot be empty!");
  return false;
 }
 else (valTxt.length<5){
  alert("You must enter at least 5 characters!")
  return false;
 }
  openWin();
  return true;
 }
 
function openWin{
 myWin= open('mypopup.html', '_blank');
}
```

As you can see I've tried many different ways to call upon the openWin function yet still nothing happens, clearly I'm doing something wrong. Apologies if this question has been asked in a different way already.

Comment: Look in the developer tools console, you should see an error - around `else (valTxt.length<5){` perhaps that should be `else if (valTxt.length<5){`

Comment: Hi, sorry, that was a leftover from all the different things I was trying but thanks for reminding me of dev tools, I really should use that more.